# Symfony - deep cloning functional test

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I am trying to write I functional test for my deep cloning entity method `__clone()` on my Symfony project, which is defined in my method class..

I am new at writing tests and I can not find any source where I can get an info about this specific operation. This is what I got so far:

```
public function testDuplicate()
{

    $userInProgress = $this->fixtureLoader->getReferenceRepository()->getReference(UserFixtures::USER_1);

    $data = [
        "name" => "John Doe"
    ];

    $expected = [
        "name" => "John Doe",
        "status" => "IN_PROGRESS",
        "assignee" => [
            "uuid" => "4e7c77d5-8e36-4319-b250-050d241621dc",
        ]
        "archived" => FALSE
    ];

    $client->request('POST',
        self::API_URL . self::USER_ENDPOINT . 'copy/' . $userInProgress->getId(),
        [],
        [],
        [
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/ld+json',
            'HTTP_ACCEPT'  => 'application/ld+json'
        ],
        json_encode($data)
    );

    //assert
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    $response = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
    $this->assertArraySubset($expected, json_decode($response, true));
}
```

This will run my test but I am not sure if it will actually test if deep cloning is set as it should?

Can anybody help?

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Where are you cloning anything in the given code?

Comment: $userInProgress has it's related tables that are deep cloned. My question is how to implement that deep clone testing here? There is also $excepted array which is response and $data are the params that are needed for that request.. @NicoHaase

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What exactly are "related tables" that you want to clone? And why does this code to test for deep-cloning contain a HTTP call? Wouldn't it be easier to craft the object to be cloned, run the code to clone it, and check whether the clone is equal to the original object?

Comment: Well that is the type of guidance I need. I got stuck in the loop with having no idea what to do. I have User table which is related to copy content table and when cloning user table __clone() method clones related copy_content rows by id. And I wanted to write test for that. @NicoHaase